# Safest way to change the permissions of this file so that I can can configure tor package repository and add :

Tags: tor-install

Safest way to change the permissions of this file so that I can can configure tor package repository and add :
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org < Byzantium> main
deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org < Bytzantium> main

to tor.list file I created in /etc/apt/sources list.d

And received not a directory when trying to shift to it i tried to shift to the file in root as well. See picture[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit it with root account. No need to change permissions.
Why do you want to cd into a file? tor.list is a file, not a directory.

Comment: Thanks I was able to edit the file

Comment: I was able to edit the file and add the entries but now im on step 3 and 4 and nothing seems to happen … Step 3

wget -qO- https: // deb.torproject. org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
…
Step 4

#apt update
#apt install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring

Comment: "nothing seems to happen" What does that mean? wget not working? No keyring file created? apt not working? Any error messages? Also: How about sticking to one question and not starting multiple ones on the same topic?

Comment: thanks for the help i found the help i needed here https://docs.j7k6.org/tor-debian-install/